# Spark(scala) Maven Project gives class not found error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

Spark Version: 3.1.0

I am new to maven with spark and scala. I am trying to create a project and write a spark file using sparksession to count number of words in a text file but I get following error when I run the code:

POM Used:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sparkscala</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- for fatjar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-scala-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.15.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute></execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Project Structure:

> [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcW9h.png)

Code 'WordCount.scala':

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Sample {
  def main(args:Array[String]) ={ println("Hello World");
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("WordCount").master("local[*]").getOrCreate
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Hello World
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/02/25 20:07:37 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.1.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationContext.<init>(Configuration.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:571)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2474)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2474)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2678)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:942)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:936)
    at com.sparkscala.mavenproject.Sample$.main(Sample.scala:5)
    at com.sparkscala.mavenproject.Sample.main(Sample.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.UnmodifiableMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

I have included the apache commons collection jar :
[collections jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Vga.png)

Please help me in resolving this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note, you should not use Spark 3.1.0, it's not an official release : https://spark.apache.org/news/next-official-release-spark-3.1.1.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by using the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```